# Dask warning provide an explicit output types

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am performing the following operation using Dask.

```py
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import pandas as pd
    
    salary_df = pd.DataFrame({"Salary":[10000, 50000, 25000, 30000, 7000]})
    salary_category = pd.DataFrame({"Hi":[5000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 90000],
                            "Low":[0,  5001, 20001, 25001, 30001],
                            "category":["Very Poor", "Poor", "Medium", "Rich", "Super Rich" ]
                            })
    sal_ddf = dd.from_pandas(salary_df, npartitions=10)
    salary_category.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(salary_category['Low'],salary_category['Hi'],closed='both')
    sal_ddf['Category'] = sal_ddf['Salary'].apply(lambda x : salary_category.iloc[salary_category.index.get_loc(x)]['category'])
```

I do get the results but there is a warning on the line below

```
      sal_ddf['Category'] = sal_ddf['Salary'].apply(lambda x : salary_category.iloc[salary_category.index.get_loc(x)]['category'])

    You did not provide metadata, so Dask is running your function on a small dataset to guess output types. It is possible that Dask will guess incorrectly.
    To provide an explicit output types or to silence this message, please provide the `meta=` keyword, as described in the map or apply function that you are using.
      Before: .apply(func)
      After:  .apply(func, meta=('Salary', 'object'))
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing keyword argument here is `meta`. Dask generates an automatic suggestion (in the warning message):

```
  After:  .apply(func, meta=('Salary', 'object'))
```

As this is a warning message, for many use cases specifying `meta` is optional, but could be useful if you want to be explicit about the `dtype` of the calculated variables.

Running the snippet below should not generate the warning message:

```py
# extracted your code into `func` for readability only
func = lambda x: salary_category.iloc[salary_category.index.get_loc(x)]['category']

sal_ddf['Category'] = sal_ddf['Salary'].apply(func, meta=('Salary', 'object'))
```

For more details this link might be useful: [meta](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-design.html).